# Entity Framework: Metadata informations for relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is there any way to get the metadata informations for the relationships?

```
public partial class Contact
{
    public Contact()
    {
        this.Addresses = new HashSet<Address>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public partial class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ContactId { get; set; }
}
```

How the entity framework knows, that the ContactId is a foreign key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no metadata, it's done by conventions, in the blog post below you can find some more info:

[Conventions for Code First](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/06/01/conventions-for-code-first.aspx)

It's possible to add metadata by decorating the properties with attributes, but that's not necessary.